# SQL query to return records matching 0 or 00 or 000 or ... only

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I build a query that will return, from an SQL Server table, records containing one or n "0" (zero) only.

```
 600002340234  ==> should not be returned
 0000000 ==> should be returned
 0 ==> should be returned
 00 ==> should be returned
 93800e3 ==> should not be returned
 9103300020 ==> should not be returned
```

At the moment I am doing something like the following but this is not ideal

```
select * from table
where field like '0' or field like '00' ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it should have non-zero length and it should *not* contain anything that is *not* a `0`:

```
select * from table
where LEN(field) > 0 and field not like '%[^0]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want records which:

- Begin with a zero
- Do not contain anything which is not a zero.

Like this:

```
where field like '0%' and not field like '%[^0]%'
```